# User data validation not working

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I am trying to validate a login form with CodeIgniter and jquery. I'm using the `form_validation` library of CodeIgniter. When the user clicks the login button the form is submitted and the jquery function is called.If there's anything wrong with the data, the controller function passes the error messages as `json` to the jquery function. The problem is that  the error messages are not being displayed in the form. The only thing that shows up is  the json array in a blank page. 
This is the `html form`:

```
<form class="col-md-12 center-block" action='<?php echo base_url();?>hyr/proceso' method='post' name='proceso' id='hyrForm'>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="mesazhe"></div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text"  name='email' id='email'class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="E-mail" >
        </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
                </div>
                <input type="password" name='fjalekalim' id='fjalekalim' class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Fjalekalimi">
            </div>
                </div>
<div class="modal-footer">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="hyr()">Hyr</button>
  </div>

        </form>
```

This is the `jquery` function:

```
function hyr()
    {

$(".text-danger").remove();
$(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
$("#hyrForm").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {  
             if(response.sukses===false) {
                $('.text-danger').remove();
                if(response.mesazhe instanceof Object) {
                    $.each(response.mesazhe, function(index, value) {
                        var id = $("#"+index);
                        id
                        .closest('.form-group')
                        .removeClass('has-error')
                        .removeClass('has-success')
                        .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                        .after(value);

                    });
                } else {
                    $(".mesazhe").html('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                      '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Mbylle"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                      '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.mesazhe+
                    '</div>');
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
}
```

Part of the controller function:

```
    $validues = array('sukses' => false, 'mesazhe' => array());
     $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
       $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-
     danger">','</p>');

if($this->form_validation->run() === true) {
        $rezultati = $this->validim->validim();

    if($rezultati){
        $e=$this->input->post('email');
        if($e=='admin@yahoo.com'){
        redirect('lista_perdoruesve');
    }   
    else{
        redirect('perdorues_faqjaKryesore');
    }
    }
    else{
         $validues['sukses'] = false;
    $validues['mesazhe'] = "Nuk ekziston asnje perdorues me keto te dhena!";
    }
        }
        else{
            $validues['sukses'] = false;
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $validues['mesazhe'][$key] = form_error($key);  
      }
        }
        echo json_encode($validues);
```

Comment: You should prevent form submitting because the site is loads <?php echo base_url();?>hyr/proceso page, and avoid to run hyr() function. Add onsubmit function to form, instead onclick to submit button like this: <form onsubmit="return mySubmitFunction()"> then prevent form submitting: function mySubmitFunction(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault(); [rest part of the code]; return false;
}

Comment: If I prevent the form from submitting how will I get the error messages?

Comment: Ah, so you don't have a clue what are you doing.. Search for javascript-ajax requests.

Comment: I added the `event.preventDefault()` function before the ajax call and now I get the error messages , but if there are no errors nothing happens on submit.

Comment: You are using ajax request, so you should code what you need in the ajax request, or you can submit the form with form.submit();

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153527/discussion-between-peter-and-eri).