# How to prevent form from submitting if there are errors?

Tags: jquery, json

I have this jquery function that gets validation messages as JSON data from a codeigniter controller. It is called on form submit. The problem is that when there are errors, instead of seeing the error messages, I get the JSON array returned from the controller. This is the jquery function:

```
function login(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".text-danger").remove();
    $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
    $("#loginForm").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response) {
                if(response.success===false) {
                    $('.text-danger').remove();
                    if(response.message instanceof Object) {
                        $.each(response.message, function(index, value) {
                            var id = $("#"+index);
                            id
                                .closest('.form-group')
                                .removeClass('has-error')
                                .removeClass('has-success')
                                .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                                .after(value);
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".message").html('<div class="text-danger" role="alert">'+
                                           '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.message+
                                           '</div>');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

}
```

Comment: is there any error code you have writtern?

Comment: yes, the error messages are configured with `form-validation` library of CodeIgniter and they're passed as `json` to jquery

Comment: Where do you see the JSON response? On a new page or on the current page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User data validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007536/user-data-validation-not-working)

Comment: @irot  I see the json response in the url of the controller function that does the generation of  json. image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KycDk.png